# How to rotate an image inside ScrollViewer?

Tags: wpf, image, image-rotation

I try to rotate an image in a ScrollViewer (WPF), but the entire image needs to remain visible. The corners of the image are cut off, if rotation angle is for example 45. I tried setting the Width and Height of the image by calculation the surrounding rectangle of the rotated image. It works, but not if the rotation angle is over 45.

```
<Grid>
    <ScrollViewer ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Margin="0,0,0,0">
        <Image x:Name="image" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Margin="0,0,0,0" MouseDown="image_MouseDown" MouseRightButtonDown="image_MouseRightButtonDown" MouseLeftButtonDown="image_MouseLeftButtonDown">
            <Image.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform x:Name="scal"/>
                    <SkewTransform/>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="90" x:Name="rot"/>
                    <TranslateTransform/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </Image.RenderTransform>
        </Image>
    </ScrollViewer>

</Grid>
```

Comment: Please add the XAML code, and C# code you wrote.

Comment: You need to maintain `aspect ratio`, then there would be now such issue.

Comment: I used Image.LayoutTransform instead of Image.RenderTransform and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `ViewBox` in the following structure:

```
<ScrollViewer Width="100" Height="100" Background="Black" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <Viewbox Width="100" Height="100">
        <Border Width="100" Height="100" Background="Red" >
            <Border.LayoutTransform>
                <RotateTransform Angle="30"   />
            </Border.LayoutTransform>
        </Border>
    </Viewbox>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Note that you should set the size of the `ViewBox` and the inner `Control` (in your case the `Image`) equal to the size of the `ScrollViewer`. The `ViewBox` will adjust the size of the inner `Control`, in such a way that the ScrollBars are never Visible.

Note that I used a red Border, you can add the image.

**Edit**

Just checked it. You do not need to set the Widths, but just the size of inner Control. In other words, this works too:

```
<ScrollViewer Background="Black" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <Viewbox>
        <Border Width="1" Height="1" Background="Red" >
            <Border.LayoutTransform>
                <RotateTransform Angle="30"   />
            </Border.LayoutTransform>
        </Border>
    </Viewbox>
</ScrollViewer>
```